# Where are my own contact details

Tags: iphone

In the contact list there is no entry for my own contact details. All there is is my mobile number at the top of the list.

But I have a home landline number, desk phone at work and some email addresses, how do I view/use these?

Comment: Tap your entry at the top of the list, it's really a full contact and can be edited as such.

Comment: @Tyson You should make that into an answer, Tyson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your own contact:

1) Make a new contact with your name and info, like you'd make one for someone else.

2) Go to `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars`

3) Under the `Contacts` section should be an option called `My Info`. Select this, then pick your new contact from the pop up list.

Comment: Nice one, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Tap your entry at the top of the list, it's really a full contact and can be edited as such.

Comment: Cool, it works, cheers mate.